# Glass bottle's inside remains opaque in blender render bottle

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

Trying to use Blender render to create a glass bottle, however transparency settings do not effect the inside of the bottle even though it's all one object.

[image]

Comment: Try increasing the *Depth* setting in the *Transparency* section, just off the bottom edge of your screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the *Depth* is set high enough in *Material > Transparency*:

[image]

Note that setting it to very high values will increase rendertime significantly (note the rendertime recorded in the top left of the gif), so try and use as low a value as you can get away with.